# "ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve service name" with HammerDB

Tags: oracle11g

I am new to HammerDb and just started to build a schema under TPC-C through the steps provided in the tutorial pdf.
After configuring the Build Options with the DB details when I try to build a schema I get this error-
***Error in Virtual User 1: ORA-12154: TNS:could not resolve service name***

Now the thing is I have configured the same DB in Jmeter as well and its working smoothly, so I don't think the problem is with the DB settings. What am I missing here.

Also the tutorial says that with the help of slider provided, I can change the number of warehouses and asked to set it as 10 to start with but the slider is hard to control. It races from value being 1 to 33 and none in between.So, is it really possible to set in-between values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The HammerDB forums are the best place for asking HammerDB related questions to get a quick answer. Oracle tools such as tnsping are the best way to resolved connectivity issues, if you can sqlplus to the database then HammerDB uses exactly the same underlying OCI connectivity to connect. 
As with a lot of sliders simply click to either side of the slider to move the value by 1 each time.

Steve